# Adding a client-side event handler for TFS GetCompleted

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I want to know when (using either Visual Studio, or TF.exe) the client triggers **Get Latest Version**. Because I want to trigger my scripted build process to behave differently when this has occurred.

I have already tried to create a WinForms application that implements an event handler, as below:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var collections = RegisteredTfsConnections.GetProjectCollections();
        var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collections.First().Uri, CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
        var vcServer = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        vcServer.GetCompleted += VcServer_GetCompleted;
        vcServer.Getting += VcServer_Getting;
    }

    private void VcServer_GetCompleted(object sender, WorkspaceEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("VcServer_GetCompleted" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void VcServer_Getting(object sender, GettingEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("VcServer_Getting" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

But it would appear that these event handlers only listen to this instance of VersionControlServer, not globally on the client workstation.

Comment: I would be surprised if it were different! These events are tied to a VersionControlServer object represting a connection to the server not to a folder of your local system.

Comment: @Tyson, Giulio is correct. And can you provide some examples on why it doesn't work as your expectation?

Comment: I am also having the same problem... Any resolutions?